# How to use 'ng-if' in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Consider:

```
<h3 style="color:#00bfff;margin:-14px 0 16px 0px" class="inline" *ng-if="data.for == 'next'">
    {{data.bannerText}}<sup><small>{{data.super}}</small></sup>
</h3>
<span class="NotinStockGrey"> {{data.textOne}} </span>
<span style="color:#00bfff"> {{data.textTWo}} </span>
```

Error:

> zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 
> Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'h3'. ("0Fb;margin:-16px 0 16px 0px">

Answer (score 8):

It's *[ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)*:

```
*ngIf="..."
```

(not `ng-if`)

You also need to add `BrowserModule` (`AppModule`) or `CommonModule` to `imports: []` of `@NgModule(...)` to make it available for the components of a module.

Comment: What is the story about `ngIf` vs. `*ngIf`?

Comment: `*` indicates a short-form syntax (the long form is used very rarely directly) and `ngIf` is a structural directive https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#shorthand-examples

Answer (score 4):

You have to use *ngIf instead of *ng-if.

```
<h3 style="color:#00bfff;margin:-14px 0 16px 0px" class="inline" *ngIf="data.for == 'next'">{{data.bannerText}}<sup><small>{{data.super}}</small></sup></h3><span class="NotinStockGrey" > {{data.textOne}} </span><span style="color:#00bfff">{{data.textTWo}}</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

The attribute ng-if is changed in Angular 2 and later, so simply use `*ngIf="whatever"`

Something like the below:

```
<div *ngIf="userObservable | async as user; else loading">
  Hello {{user.last}}, {{user.first}}!
</div>
```

Or something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="mate">
  Hello {{ mate }}!
</div>
```