# Enable or disable some sidemenu content according to user login

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

i used Angular 2 to create a web, i want to enable or disable some sidebar components according to user login data, login data of user is stored in json and through a Qwebchannel a token is passed in locolhost for authentication, now what i want is to enable or disable some sidebar component according to user login token...

```
ReDirectToNextPage(user: string){
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 1);
    console.log('ReDirectToNextPage called from JS');
    this.tokenStorage.saveToken("login#username:" + user);
    this.router.navigate(['server-config']);
}
checkLogin() {

    if (this.tokenStorage.getToken() != undefined && this.tokenStorage.getToken() != null && this.tokenStorage.getToken().indexOf("login") != -1) {
        this.router.navigate(['server-config']);
    } else {
        const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[0];
        setTimeout(function () {
            card.classList.remove('card-hidden');
        }, 700);
    }
}
```

this is what i tried i am getting token for loggedIN user i want to show only assign rights to loggedIN user (rights vary from user login)
Thanks

Comment: can you put some code around what you have tried?

Comment: i want to get token along with that JSON data through QWEBCHANNELING

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked a lot with angular 2 but I suggest start working with angular 6+ which covers typescript , but what you need is common , ngIf 
example with angularjs :

```
<div *ngIf="isValid"> Data is valid. </div>
```

[Tutorial](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-ngif-example)

and same solution in [stackoverflow angular 2 ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582411/how-to-ng-if-in-angular-2)

If you wanted to disable it this can help you : 
[deactive angular button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676784/how-to-disable-a-button-in-angularjs)

so for example you have a jwt so you can use a boolean to check if user is authenticated or not
I hope this will help you ;)

Comment: what i want is like if user login s/he will get limited sidebar components but admin can get all of the sidebar components as it is already described in a JSON file which states the rights of user now i want to get that data from QWEBCHANNEL into my angular project.

Comment: can you give sample json
its like havePermission["option1"] : myJson["option1"] == 1 and use it on ngIf

Comment: i want solve this in typescript(.TS) file instead of HTML

Comment: maybe something like this : template = "<div>option1</div>" or "<div>option2</div>" and use {{template}} :D , I don't think this way is optimal